Combine this two-table data in a single result from two different tables
Table trusted_device_details:



DEVICE_TYPE
DEVICE_NAME
DEVICE_ID
Created Date Time
Last Accessed Date Time
IP_ADDRESS
USER_ID
CLIENT_CODE




MOBIL APP
IPHONE 6S
4455555
8-Dec-24
12/8/2024 16:01
10.1.1.1
XXX1



MOBIL APP
IPHONE 15
52344444
8-Dec-24
12/8/2024 16:01
10.1.1.6
XXX1



MOBIL APP
Ipad
788995544
9-Nov-24
12/6/2025 16:01
10.1.1.1
XXX1




Table USER_AUDIT_TRAIL:



DEVICE_TYPE
DEVICE_NAME
DEVICE_ID
Created Date Time
Last Accessed Date Time
IP_ADDRESS
USER_ID
CLIENT_CODE




MOBIL APP
IPHONE 6S
4455555
10/8/2024


XXX1
55111444


MOBIL APP
IPHONE 15
52344444
11/8/2024


XXX1
55111444


MOBIL APP
Ipad
788995544
12/9/2024


XXX1
55111444



Desired result:



DEVICE_TYPE
DEVICE_NAME
DEVICE_ID
Created Date Time
Last Accessed Date Time
IP_ADDRESS
USER_ID
CLIENT_CODE




MOBIL APP
IPHONE 6S
4455555
8-Dec-24
12/8/2024 16:01
10.1.1.1
XXX1



MOBIL APP
IPHONE 15
52344444
8-Dec-24
12/8/2024 16:01
10.1.1.6
XXX1



MOBIL APP
Ipad
788995544
9-Nov-24
12/6/2025 16:01
10.1.1.1
XXX1



MOBIL APP
IPHONE 6S
4455555
10/8/2024


XXX1
55111444


MOBIL APP
IPHONE 15
52344444
11/8/2024


XXX1
55111444


MOBIL APP
Ipad
788995544
12/9/2024


XXX1
55111444



I have tried to combine these two queries and get a result using union it's not working for me. Could you please help get the above-mentioned result.
The link between two tables is the column user_id. The result should be queried using a where condition using the client_code column from user_audit_trail this table.
The client code in trusted_device_details is always null. Also, I want the result by combining the query using the "With" function too.
--Query#1
WITH devicerank AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.channel,
        t.user_id,
        t.device_name,
        t.device_id,
        t.created_at,
        t.last_accessed_at,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, device_id
                          ORDER BY t.last_accessed_at DESC) AS rank_number
    FROM
        trusted_device_details t
)
SELECT
    channel          AS device_type,
    device_name      AS device_name,
    device_id        AS device_id,
    created_at       AS "Created Date Time",
    last_accessed_at AS "Last Accessed Date Time ",
    NULL             AS ip_address,
    user_id,
    NULL             AS "CLIENT_CODE",
    rank_number
FROM
    devicerank
WHERE
    rank_number = 1
;

--Query#2
WITH devicerank AS 
(
    SELECT
        application_id,
        user_id,
        client_code,
        device_name,
        device_id,
        ip,
        TIMESTAMP,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, device_id
                          ORDER BY u.timestamp DESC) AS rank_number
    FROM
        user_audit_trail u
)
SELECT
    application_id AS device_type,
    device_name    AS device_name,
    device_id      AS device_id,
    TIMESTAMP      AS "Created Date Time",
    NULL           AS "Last Accessed Date Time ",
    ip             AS ip_address,
    user_id,
    client_code    AS "CLIENT_CODE",
    rank_number
FROM
    devicerank
WHERE
    rank_number = 1


You can use UNION ALL to get the combined result from both the tables.
EDIT : Based on comment that client_code is updated to be NULL.
Fiddle
WITH devicerank_trusted AS 
(
    SELECT
        t.device_type,
        t.device_name,
        t.device_id,
        t.created_date_time AS created_at,
        t.last_accessed_date_time AS last_accessed_at,
        t.user_id,
        ip_address,
        client_code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.user_id, t.device_id ORDER BY t.created_date_time DESC) AS rank_number
    FROM
        trusted_device_details t
),
devicerank_audit AS 
(
    SELECT
        u.device_type,
        u.device_name,
        u.device_id,
        u.created_date_time AS created_at,
        u.last_accessed_date_time as last_accessed_at,
        u.user_id,
        u.ip_address,
        u.client_code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id, u.device_id ORDER BY u.created_date_time DESC) AS rank_number
    FROM
        user_audit_trail u
    WHERE
        u.client_code IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT
    device_type,
    device_name,
    device_id,
    created_at AS "Created Date Time",
    last_accessed_at AS "Last Accessed Date Time",
    ip_address,
    user_id,
    client_code
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT * FROM devicerank_trusted WHERE rank_number = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM devicerank_audit WHERE rank_number = 1
    )
ORDER BY device_name, device_id;

Output


The input to get the result should be using the client code. Since, there can be more than one user id for a client code.

I have edited to include client_code as a filter in the where condition, but it should not matter as both client_code and user_id are present in both tables

The client code is null in the first table. I have reworded it.  Also, I need that rank which i have mentioned in the queries.

I have updated the code , see EDIT
